# Count how many consecutive days a user log in

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains every login a user makes. I need to count how many consecutive days a user log in.
I just compute the count by selecting all timestamp and cycling them with php.
Is there a more practical way to do this with mysql?

I have a `users_login` table with user and datetime column:

```
SELECT `datetime` FROM `users_login` WHERE `user_id`=`3123` order by `datetime` desc;
```

Right now I implemented a for loop to scan every `datetime` and check if the timestamp is inside the day range.

Should I keep track of the count at every login? I means, having a column `consec_days` starting from 0 and increasing by one at every daily login?

Comment: Check the gaps-and-islands tag http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands